# error: metadata-generation-failed Encountered error while generating package metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I have win 11, pip 24, py 3.13 version

with vs code i try install pandas or any pack nee weel and i get error , pls see the error

```
64941a35838675a89f451\.mesonpy-06kzgf2t
        Build type: native build
        Project name: NumPy
        Project version: 1.26.4
        Activating VS 17.9.2

        ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler cl cannot compile programs.

        A full log can be found at C:\Users\eyal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p6rwcb8e\numpy_8a1e8bd76cf64941a35838675a89f451\.mesonpy-06kzgf2t\meson-logs\meson-log.txt        
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Why I can't built wheel for install python ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pip install numpy`, it will install the latest stable version of Numpy, which currently is [1.26.4](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)

[Version 1.26.4 supports Python versions 3.9 to 3.12](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.26.4). So it doesn't support 3.13.

Use Python 3.12 to fix this error.

Answer (score -1):

thnanks

i install py 3.12

i installl the numpy now is ok , i think also the whell but get another error

```
      C:\Users\eyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Building wheel for grapheme (pyproject.toml) ... done
Created wheel for grapheme: filename=grapheme-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl size=210117 sha256=fab6e3344a863b4c6104f436b22e6cf0cf0619c5b4ba52fb4d832a6d42455ad1
Stored in directory: c:\users\eyal\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5b\aa\3b\d94434910f5e19ac7f8aa6523d74a46fe06bfcbc7e4b26caf6
Building wheel for pyaes (pyproject.toml) ... done
Created wheel for pyaes: filename=pyaes-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl size=26360 sha256=0f9d05f9ccb7b39e74090e7c9db55a5f02e120597eaccd4488c7ae725673cb9d
Stored in directory: c:\users\eyal\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\d9\43\32\ec313dd557e88e419489b9df40c04dad7b99576bde162496f8
Successfully built googletrans grapheme pyaes
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects